# Okta Client Credentails - API access

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate, okta, okta-api

I created Oka application (API Services) for machine to machine Auth. I set client authentication as "Public key / Private key".

Can someone help with Spring boot application that connects to this API via public/private key method and gets access token.

I implemented Client Secret authentication by passing credentials in header.

I am new to public/private key method. Appreciate the help.

I am trying to implement public/private key auth method to get access token from OKTA.

Comment: Is this what you need? https://github.com/oktadev/okta-private-key-jwt-python-example/blob/master/get_access_token.py  get_token() Share us at least the hello world starter :)

Comment: Yes, do we need to pass private key in payload and OKTA uses pub key to validate and send access token in response?

Answer (score 0):

For client credentials, basic auth, I am using this code:
HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

```
    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    String auth = "user name"+":"+"password";
    byte[] encodedAuth = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encode(auth.getBytes());
    httpHeaders.set("Authorization", "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth));
    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
    httpHeaders.setAccept(List.of(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    MultiValueMap<String, String> reqBodyData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    reqBodyData.add("grant_type","client_credentials");
    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(reqBodyData, httpHeaders);
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> result = (LinkedHashMap<String, String>) restTemplate.postForEntity("<<auth token end point>>",
            requestEntity, Object.class).getBody();
    String accessToken = result.get("access_token");
```

Will need to find a way for pub-private key insteasd of basic auth.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).